# How to tell if a node is touching the ground in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, game-physics

I am trying to figure out a way to have a property called `isJumping` on a SCNNode subclass. The property is set to `true` whenever the nodes `jump()` function is called and the jump is implemented using `.applyForce(x: 0, y: jumpForce, z: 0, asImpulse: true)`. However, there is no way (that I can figure out) that allows the node to set the `isJumping` property back to false. My thinking is that if there was a way to tell if the node was touching the ground or not, then this would be an ideal solution. Does anyone have any ideas on how this `isJumping` property could be implemented? Or perhaps a way to compute the `isJumping` property using physics?

##### Things I've tried:

1. Checking vertical velocity != 0

   - This doesn't work because at the peak of the jump the vertical velocity is 0. In addition, when the node is rotated to "stand up" and "lie down" using SCNActions, even though the pivot point is the nodes "foot" and never really leaves the floor, it is still considered to have a vertical velocity and thus is incorrectly labelled as in a jumping state.
2. Checking position

   - This is unreliable because if the node were to hypothetically jump onto a platform, the node would be considered in a jumping state.

##### Something that may work:

1. Applying a downward force on the physics body and check in the next frame if the y-position changed at all. If it didn't change that means it rebounded off of something and in that instance I can change the `isJumping` property to `false`. Keep in mind, ideally, I wan't to be able to do this without leaving the subclass (however, using helper classes is completely fine).

Comment: Have you considered using the contact function to set your BOOL whenever your sprite makes contact with the floor or a platform?

Comment: @sangony If you mean the scene renderer delegate methods then yes I have considered it. However, I want the node to be able to reason that it's on the ground from within its own class. Using the delegate methods would require some setup from within the view controller and I don't think there's a way a node can get a reference to the View / Scene it's in from within itself. Even if there was, a node hijacking the delegate functions seems not like a good idea. I think the best way would be a function called `isOnGround(ground: SCNNode)` or `isOnGround(groundLevel: Double)` within the subclass

Comment: Is your question focusing SpriteKit or SceneKit? If it is about SceneKit I consider you to use the contact delegate to set or reset the Bool-Flag, like what @sangony says. Can you post some code?